# Is there an incompatibility between the packages calc and siunitx? (\GenericError [...])

Tags: siunitx, incompatibility, calc

The following code does not compile:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{.5cm}p{\widthof{\textbf{AAAAAAAAA}}}l}
&\textbf{AAAAAAAAA}&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
&\textbf{BBBBB}&YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, it does compile, when the line

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

is omitted. Interchanging the loading order of the packages does not help.

**Error message:**

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \GenericError ...
> #4 \errhelp \@err@ ...
> l.5 ...r}{p{.5cm}p{\widthof{\textbf{AAAAAAAAA}}}l}
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> ```

Comment: It is no siunitx but array (loaded by siunitx). It changes the way tabular preambles are handled.

Comment: The main problem is the fragile \textbf. You can robustify it `\usepackage{etoolbox}\robustify\textbf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array` package should probably have made this safe, one way to patch it is

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
    \patchcmd \@mkpream
       {\let\@sharp\relax}
       {\def\widthof##1{\unexpanded{\widthof{##1}}}\let\@sharp\relax}
       {}{}
\makeatother
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{.5cm}p{\widthof{\textbf{AAAAAAAAA}}}l}
    &\textbf{AAAAAAAAA}&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
    &\textbf{BBBBB}&YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I have now added a fix to the array package (somewhat more general than the above). The next release of LaTeX's tools (planned for December 2018) will contain this.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Unfortunately, it seems to break xcolor: `\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{4cm}|p{4cm}}
  Test
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Comment: @cjorssen that's the `table` option so `colortbl` (which did get broken) a new version of `colortbl` went to ctan yesterday so should be in distributions probably tomorrow

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This morning: `update: colortbl [593k] (47614 -> 49404) ... done`. Thank you so much for being so quick to fix things.